# Unable to make responsive aligment

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, responsive

Screenshot (The layout i look for) :

[image]

My codes

```css
body {
         background: #000000 50% 50%;
         overflow-x: hidden;
         overflow-y: hidden;
         }
        .video{
         margin: 50px 20px;
         display: grid;
         place-items: center;
         height: 80vh;
         }
         .left {
         text-align: left;
         }
         .right {
         text-align: right;
         }
         .container {
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
         }
```

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">


    <div class="left">
        <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
        <img src="https://place-hold.it/336x280" /> <br>
        <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
        <img src="https://place-hold.it/280x500" />
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="video">
      <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/500x500" />

    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
      <p style="color: blue;">title</p>
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/336x280" /> <br>
      <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/280x500" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My current code : Works fine with large desktop, big screen and resolution
But,
When i check it with small desktop, mobile and small resolution screen, than the layout getting missed up.
How to i make this responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed most of the code from your `CSS` and used `flex-wrap` to wrap the `divs` if screen shrinks and added a `justify-content:space-between` for the space.

`Change:`added button inside video `div` since video itself is a div i gave it `display:flex` and changed the `flex-direction:column` `align-items` to center them and `gap:30px` between `p` `img` `button`

```css
body {
        background: #000000 50% 50%;

    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    
    }
    .video {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 30px;
    }

    .vid-btn {
        padding: 20px 150px;

    }
```

```html
<div class="container">


        <div class="left">
            <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/336x280" /> <br>
            <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/280x500" />
        </div>


        <div class="video">
            <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/500x500" />
             <button class="vid-btn">Button</button>

        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/336x280" />
            <p style="color: blue;">Title</p>
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/280x500" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works. But how to add the button below `img` in Video `DIV`. When i add button the space between img and button is big.

Comment: i updated the code and added the button you wanted